# кросс-доменный запрос cредствами js

Tags: javascript, парсер, xmlhttprequest, cors

Господа, никак не могу понять в чем проблема. На странице по нажатию выполняется js код который выуживает ссылку со страницы, которая ведет на файл на стороннем домене, после чего(в теории) делается XMLHttpRequest запрос, который получает данный файл в переменную как строку.

Но проблема заключается в том, что после получения ссылки и попытки получить ее содержимое выбивает ошибку

> Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного
> источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на (тут ссылка на файл).
> (Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»).

Пытаюсь получить содержимое файла через

```
var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;

var xhr = new XHR();
xhr.open('GET', urlindef, true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.onload = function() {
  alert( this.responseText );
}
xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert( 'Ошибка ' + this.status );
}
xhr.send();
```

Где *urlindef* - ссылка на сам файл который загружается.

Ну и соответственно выбивает ошибку в alert(). При этом если ту же ссылку пробовать открыть в браузере этом же, в новой вкладке - все открывается и дает скачать мгновенно. Как это можно исправить и корректно составить запрос на получение данных? Сразу оговорюсь - у меня нет доступа к тому серверу и я не могу прописать там в header или htaccess параметры Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * .

Просто я не могу понять почему через браузер руками все ок, а по сути отправляя с этой же страницы запрос у меня выбивает ошибку, хотя по идее куки все подключаю как надо.

Comment: Потому что, в браузере Вы лично, отдавая себе отчет в своих действиях и не являясь роботом(надеюсь) запрашиваете ресурсы по данному урлу. Во втором же случае  доступ к стороннему ресурсу осуществляется программными средствами, что противоречит политикам безопасности.

Comment: @МихаилРебров и что, данный запрет на уровне браузера вообще никак нельзя обойти? Просто я проверял и у меня даже все заголовки совпадают как надо, сервер отдает код 200, но браузер обрубает запрос на корню.

Comment: Вам надо проксировать ваш запрос тогда через ваш сервер или использовать публичный сервер [cors-anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-jsonp

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Но это для работы с API, для других ресурсов тоже видел похожие по принципу примеры....ну или как сказали выше - прокси

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, проксировать не прокатит, потому что он хочет `withCredentials`, а на его прокси чужие куки никто не отправит.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, jsonp тоже требует изменений на том сервере, к которому нет доступа.

Comment: @Qwertiy возможно, что `withCredentials` ему и не нужен на самом дел, т.к. вангую, что ТС нашел код на просторах интернета.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я прочитал что без этого параметра невозможен запрос на другой домен посредствам XMLHttpRequest. В моем понимании данный параметр отправляет все нужные данные для авторизации клиента, что ему может сайт доверять и прочее. Возможно я прав? Может есть какой-то корректный способ вбить в запрос куки с текущей страницы и указать кастомный реферрер без этого параметра?

Comment: У вас в данном случае проблема не с куками, а с тем, что браузер запрещает запросы на сторонний сервер. Разберитесь сначала с CORS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Сразу оговорюсь - у меня нет доступа к тому серверу и я не могу прописать там в header или htaccess параметры Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * .

Значит сделать то, что ты хочешь (запрос с credential'ами), ты тоже не можешь. Всё.